RHEL on AWS: Red Hat Insights Client suggests changing cipher rules
I have had the following suggestion for my Servers on the insights client.
SSH security is decreased when insecure cipher or hmac is enabled in the crypto policy
The playbook remediation doesn't seem to work.  Neither does the linked red hat knowledge base article.  https://access.redhat.com/articles/7041246
More concerning is that I have never touched these policies, the incident reports that the systems had this issue as of 3 days ago but the 'Modified date' was 18th July 24
What happened to my servers to suddenly allow these insecure ciphers?  Does this indicate a data breach?  Or could it be AWS changing things?

In general: Security insights change over time so what was acceptable in the past may no longer be suitable or recommended any longer today. So assuming foul play would not be my first option. (Default) settings from RHEL 8 (released 2019) or RHEL 9 (released 2022) were established well before those release dates so revising them might not be a bad thing but could break compatibility so running updated won’t make those changes for you. (No red hat insight enabled system at hand so can’t check the internals)

this is from RedHat insights team.

More concerning is that I have never touched these policies, the incident reports that the systems had this issue as of 3 days ago but the 'Modified date' was 18th July 24

This Advisor rule is created to check if there is insecure cipher or hmac configured for sshd service(the initial version is released on 18th July 24).
This Advisor rule checks the output of nmap command when crypto is enabled. However, nmap is not installed by default, so we released a update(last week) which checks crypto config files when nmap is not installed and crypto is enabled. This is why it shows your system hit this issue 3 days ago and the 'Modified date' was 18th July 24.

The playbook remediation doesn't seem to work. Neither does the linked red hat knowledge base article. https://access.redhat.com/articles/7041246.

please open a case via the portal: https://access.redhat.com, then please upload your playbook remediation and insights archive, let's research it on the case.
# insights-client --no-upload

